# Корректное изменение имени файла

Tags: php

Подскажите, как правильно ренеймить файл при загрузке его на сервер ? Разделять на левую и правую части не разумно т.к. это легко сломать. Например, взять и назвать файл file.photo.2020.jpg.

Подскажите, как корректно заренеймить, чтобы все, что до .jpg приняло вид, например, time()..а то в голову лезут мудреные и громоздкие решения :(

Comment: Получайте расширение файла с помощью `pathinfo($path)['extension']`, и формируйте новое имя, подставляя расширение.

Comment: @Эдуард прочитал про функцию - применил. Премного благодарен :)